# JPA default persistence unit

Tags: jpa, default, persistence.xml, persistence-unit

I get exception "There is no default persistence unit in this deployment." can I somehow mark unit as default?(I have only one persistence unit, so Id rather not call it by name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to call PU's by name.

Comment: You don't have to call a PU by name if you are injecting.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing it through code rather than letting the container manage it.  In which case you have to specify by name.

My unit test code has this code block to do this.

```
@Before
public void createEntityManagerFactory() throws IOException {
    final Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/inmemory.properties"));
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default", p);
}
```

However, my application code looks like this.

```
/**
 * Injected persistence context.
 */
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```